# How to properly setup a CORS POST request with Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, cors

I have an application where the backend is hosted on a different server than the front end. The backend is already set up to allow requests from the front end and we confirmed this with a POST request using the jQuery `$.ajax` method. Nonetheless, what I would really like to do is to configure the save method on a Backbone model to do the same or something similar such that it also works with Backbone. This is the code I have right now:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://someurl.com/controller',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: '{"some":"json"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData) {
        // handle success
    },
    error: function (error) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

I would like to do something like this instead:

```
myModel.save(null, function(data){
    // handle response appropriately
});
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom method to save which does exactly the same as I did before, but at least it is better encapsulated since the method is defined on the model.

```
        saveFunction: function(attributes, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: this.url,
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: attributes
            }).done(function( data ) {
                   callback(data);
            }); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`Model.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync) to customize the requests sent to your server. For example, to add the `crossdomain: true` attribute :

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'https://someurl.com/controller',

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        _.defaults(options || (options = {}), {
            crossDomain: true
        });

        return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
    }
});

var m = new M();
m.save();
```